# Using conditions in different triggers

Tags: c#

I am having a lot of difficulties trying to find out more about how to type out a set of codes and reference it at other parts of the CS file.

For example, I have a simple "switch statement" with a label. Instead of typing it out 2 or 3 times, I would like to just be able to call it. Below is a quick illustration of what I am tyring to do.

```
//Begin Reuseable Codes
string title;
switch (Request.QueryString["parameter"]){
 case "first":
       title = "123";
       break;
 case "two":
       title = "ABC";
       break;
}
lblDDSubject.Text = "My message" + title
//End Reuseable Codes


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    call the above reusable codes;
}

protected void something_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    call the above reusable codes here also;
]
```

Since I am a super-noob, may the assistor(s) respond in less abstract way?

Answer (score 1):

You could place your reusable code inside a method and have it return the title.

```
private string GetTitle(HttpRequest Request)
{
  string title;

  switch (Request.QueryString["parameter"]){
   case "first":
       title = "123";
       break;
   case "two":
       title = "ABC";
       break;
   }
   return title;
}
```

and then call it from your Page_Load method

```
string title = GetTitle(this.Request);
```

Answer (score 1):

Methods are for these purposes. You write your code in a method

```
private string DoSomething()
{
    string title;
    switch (Request.QueryString["parameter"]){
     case "first":
           title = "123";
           break;
     case "two":
           title = "ABC";
           break;

    return "My message" + title;
}
```

Then call this method like below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblDDSubject.Text = DoSomething();
}

protected void something_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblDDSubject.Text = DoSomething();
]
```

Have a look to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) post.

Answer (score 1):

If you always use a label you could even extend those other answers with the following, you could even replace the switch cases if you want, althought I don't think you'll need something like that.

```
    public static void Reusable(HttpRequest httpRequest, string parameter, Label label)
    {
        string title = "";
        switch (httpRequest.QueryString[parameter])
        {
            case "first":
                title = "123";
                break;
            case "two":
                title = "ABC";
                break;
        }
        label.Text = "My message" + title;
    }
```

And call it like this:

```
    Reusable(Request, "parameter", lblDDSubject);
```